# How to change the background of a button with a link on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a button with a link within it. I want the button's background color and the link's text color to change when I hover over the button. However, I can't get the link's color to change when I hover over the button, only when I hover over the link. Here's what I have.

```css
button {
   background-color: navy;
   padding: 1%;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
   border: 4px inset darkgrey;
}
button a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
}
button a:hover {
   color: navy;
}
button:hover {
   background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button><a href="random.html">Lorem ipsum</a></button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Buttons cannot contain links and vice versa, it's invalid HTML

Comment: buttons are type of inputs, they can't have a and a:hover ... read about button - https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_hover

Comment: When you say buttons "cannot" contain links do you mean "shouldn't"? Technically you can, but it's probably bad practice.

Comment: You could change the button to a div and style that and then include div:hover a { color: navy;}

Comment: @Kyle actually against the spec. See for example “there must be no Interactive content“ in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not very complicated, like gift!

```css
button {
   background-color: navy;
   padding: 1%;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
   border: 4px inset darkgrey;
}
button a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
}
button:hover {
   background-color: white;
}
button:hover a {
   color: navy;
}
```

```html
<button><a href="random.html">Lorem ipsum</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered this and deleted it, but it worked:

```
button:hover a {
    color: navy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by other users, you shouldn't place a link inside a button. If you need the button to open another page you could place the button inside a form and specify the destination on the action, like this:

```
<form action="random.html">
    <button>Lorem ipsum</button>
</form>
```